# how to configure nginx for long poll (and php)

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm creating a simple chat app. Have installed nginx on Ubuntu 11.10, with PHP via fast-cgi. To get a feel for performance, I made a simple PHP file that sleeps 10 seconds then reports the time. Calling this with several browser instances (different browsers, different machines) the response becomes sluggish after about 10 instances, a lot less than expected (was hoping to not see any deterioration until the hundreds, though that would not be practical using manual browser testing).

I'm a web-dev, not sys-admin, maybe out of my depth? Not looking for optimal solution (searching reveals nginx should be able to handle 10k per core), but a few hundred would be great.

There's also the Nginx Push Stream Module, but I can't figure out how to install it, and seems yet another technology to get to grips with. Should basic out of the box nginx be able to cope with my expectations, i.e. 100+ long-term connections using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push stream module will technically do what you want it to do -- set up a url in which you can push updates to that in turn can be polled by a pubsub in your client side code.

In order to install the push stream module, you need to get the latest source of nginx, get the source for that module, compile that, then recompile your nginx **with the path to the new module source as one of the flags**. See how i did that, here:

[Recompiling nginx after using apt-get install nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537426/recompiling-nginx-after-using-apt-get-install-nginx)

If the restart of your nginx server does not list that module in the listed flags for the current instance, then you didn't properly overwrite the nginx files during recompile. Make sure you include the `--sbin-path` flag to ensure overwriting to the correct directory.

Once you've confirmed that it is in fact installed and running in nginx, then follow the steps provided by @baba

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure the end points for subscribing and publishing. Add the following to your nginx.conf file:

```
# internal publish endpoint (keep it private / protected)
location /publish {
  set $push_channel_id $arg_id;      #/?id=239aff3 or somesuch
  push_publisher;

  push_store_messages on;            # enable message queueing
  push_message_timeout 2h;           # messages expire after 2 hours, set to 0 to never expire
  push_message_buffer_length 10;     # store 10 messages
}

# public long-polling endpoint
location /subscribe {
  push_subscriber;

  # how multiple listener requests to the same channel id are handled
  # - last: only the most recent listener request is kept, 409 for others.
  # - first: only the oldest listener request is kept, 409 for others.
  # - broadcast: any number of listener requests may be long-polling.
  push_subscriber_concurrency broadcast;
  set $push_channel_id $arg_id;
  default_type  text/plain;
}
```

See Documentations

http://www.brentsowers.com/2011/06/http-long-polling-aka-comet-with-nginx.html

http://www.igvita.com/2009/10/21/nginx-comet-low-latency-server-push/

If you want to convert it to a full `COMET` server you can use

https://github.com/slact/nginx_http_push_module

Answer (score 0):

Can you cover how you have configured Nginx so far? and what you thought about your configurations? In my own opinion, the most critical configs for you should be worker processes, worker connections, open_file_cache and keep alives here. Here is a good writeup covering all of them:

http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/04/optimizing-nginx-for-high-traffic-loads/

also you might want to take a look more into the directives:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule

I've configured worker processes and worker connections before with 2 and 10240 before, with keepalives > 20. hope that helps you.

** Oh, I also forgot to mention -- maybe Opcode caching can work for you? Try installing PHP-APC.

Comment: Settings: worker_processes 2; worker_connections 1024; I should mention this was on Amazon micro instance, RackSpace 256, 512MB instances - pretty much the same response.

Comment: Cool! i also use an Amazon Micro instance. However, I think what he needs is for long-executing scripts.. The worker_connections bump to 10240 I did was because I am running a Magento app on it and so that I could not see any performance hit when I do alot of reindexes. I also coupled my config with Varnish cache and PHP-APC.